# Rails close without saving from edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I have a typical CRUD app, I would like to add a link next to the f.submit that allows you to go back to the index without saving changes. I thought it would be as simple as just making a link to the index, but it's saving changes anyway.

```
<%= button_to 'Close Without Saving', users_path %>
<%= f.submit %>
```

What's the rails way of handling this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to):

> [`button_to`] Generates a form containing a single button that submits to the URL created by the set of options.

So using `button_to` inside a form will attempt to create a nested form but HTML forms don't nest. The result will be an HTML structure something like this:

```
<form>
    <form><!-- from button_to -->
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <input type="submit"><!-- from f.submit -->
</form>
```

But the browser will ignore the inner `<form>` and assume you meant this:

```
<form>
    <input type="submit"><!-- from button_to -->
    <input type="submit"><!-- from f.submit -->
</form>
```

Then pressing either `<input type="submit">` will submit the outer form.

You can either create another submit button in the outer form and the controller can check which button was pressed or you can use `link_to` and style the link to match your submit button (or leave it styled like a link depending on your preference).

Comment: yep, making a link_to made it work appropriately. I didn't realize to button acted differently, I thought it just displayed differently.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="button" onClick="location.href='<%= users_path %>'">Close Without Saving</button>
<%= f.submit %>
```

This also worked... went back to basics and used good old fashioned HTML.